# Reuse pattern in JSON schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

Is it possible to define a regex once and re-use it? I have a few pretty complex regexes which I would like to use as the pattern for the *value* of a large number of properties of various different object in my schema. Doing Copy paste of this looks like asking for trouble further down the line, but I can't seem to find a suitable re-use example anywhere.

Cut down schema which illustrates what I want to do.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "patterns": {
    "fqdn_or_ipaddress": "(?=^.{4,253}$)(^((?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,63}$)||(((?:^[0-9])(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}))(?![0-9])$)|(^\\*$))",
  },
  "properties": {
    "server_hostname" : {
       "type":"string",
       "pattern": {"#ref", "#/patterns/address"},
    },
    "proxy_hostname" : {
       "type":"string",
       "pattern": {"#ref", "#/patterns/address"},
    }   
  }
}
```

Doesn't validate here http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ because "pattern" is not a string. Is this a hole in the re-use. I've looked at patternProperties, but that seems to solve completely different use case.

Answer (score 10):

You can only `$ref` a schema.  You would need to do something like this.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "server_hostname" : {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/fqdn_or_ipaddress",
      "description": "The server hostname"
    },
    "proxy_hostname" : {
      "allOf": [{ "$ref": "#/definitions/fqdn_or_ipaddress" }],
      "description": "The proxy hostname"
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "fqdn_or_ipaddress": {
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "(?=^.{4,253}$)(^((?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,63}$)||(((?:^[0-9])(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}))(?![0-9])$)|(^\\*$))"
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

I added two examples of how to extend from a `$ref`.  In the first, you can just add the `description`.  It will be ignored, but it is not an error.  Since `description` is just a meta-data keyword, this shouldn't be a problem.

In the second example, you can use `allOf` to wrap the `$ref` and you can add whatever keywords you need (even non-meta data keywords).

Comment: Great. Thanks that would work if I didn't have to add a description to each property. Is there a way of "extending" a schema?

  "properties": {
    "server_hostname" : { "$ref": "#/patterns/fqn_or_ipaddress", "description": "bla bla bla" },

Comment: @smcp I updated the answer to address your question.

Comment: Great exactly what I wanted

Comment: See the next answer which does all the naming correctly

Comment: I fixed the typos, (including one more that wasn't identified). I must have been very tired to have made that many mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44839075/4366876) highlights key structure for reusing the defined pattern. However, the example does not validate as:

1. The definition is given as part of the object reference with "definitions" whereas the "$ref" path is referencing a "patterns" definition that is nowhere to be found.
2. The pattern definition key is provided as "fqdn_or_ipaddress" whereas the paths in the properties refer to a "fqn_or_ipaddress" which is not defined.

Following is the corrected sample that passes the validation in the [JSON schema validator](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/):

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "server_hostname" : {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/fqdn_or_ipaddress",
      "description": "The server hostname"
    },
    "proxy_hostname" : {
      "allOf": [{ "$ref": "#/definitions/fqdn_or_ipaddress" }],
      "description": "The proxy hostname"
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "fqdn_or_ipaddress": {
      "type": "string",
      "fqdn_or_ipaddress": "(?=^.{4,253}$)(^((?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,63}$)||(((?:^[0-9])(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}))(?![0-9])$)|(^\\*$))"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Next time consider using the "edit" feature instead of creating a new answer to fix typos.